# why the data is not shown after being retrieved from aws api gateway (react native)

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-api-gateway

Firstly, I have tested the data retrieval on AWS API Gateway. The response body is exactly what I need, which is like this:

> {"body":[{"lastUpdateTimestamp":0,"currLocation":{"latitude":"5.355308","longitude":"100.300039"},"nextStop":"IPS","isRunning":1,"currStop":"SC","bleAddress":"F1:E4:E4:AD:24:50","busCarplate":"PLK5574"},{"lastUpdateTimestamp":0,"currLocation":{"latitude":"5.355308","longitude":"100.300039"},"nextStop":"IPS","isRunning":1,"currStop":"SC","bleAddress":"E3:60:15:DA:38:E2","busCarplate":"PJK7834"}]}

Then, I want to retrieve data in my React Native application. I am sure API_URL and API key that I put in the code are correct.
Next, I retrieve the data with the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch(API_URL, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                API_URL,
                API_HEADERS
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => setData(json))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));

        let count = data.length;
        console.log(count);

        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            console.log('API data: ', data[i]['currLocation']);
        }

    }, []);
```

However, the output that I got is like this:

```
undefined
```

I couldn't figure out what's the problem with this as there's no any error message. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you get when you make a GET request with curl or any API testing tool like postman?

Comment: @ArpitJain I got the same result like the response body that I put above.

Comment: I am not a javascript expert but you can try doing `console.log(data)` to see if data is coming at all or not.

Comment: @ArpitJain I did. But it shows no data is available. (undefined)

Comment: currLocation is not in data. Its in data's body object. Your console statement is wrong. Please console the count and the response before the for loop.

I think you can retrieve it like data.data[0].body.currLocation.